Does assignment xtensor view to xarray makes a copy of the data
I have a code which creates a xt::xarray from CV Mat by adapting:
std::array<size_t, 3> shape = {static_cast<size_t>(img.rows),
                                       static_cast<size_t>(img.cols), 2};

xt::xarray<float> arr = xt::adapt(img.ptr<float>(), shape);

Later I have a helper function to generate linearly spaced indices:
xt::xarray<float> sparsified = sparsify(arr);

where:
xt::xarray<float> sparsify(const xt::xarray<float> &arr) const
{
   
    auto yIndices = xt::linspace<int>(0, arr.shape(0) - 1, _config._sparseGridY, false);
    auto xIndices = xt::linspace<int>(0, arr.shape(1) - 1, _config._sparseGridX, false);

   
    return xt::view(arr, xt::keep(yIndices), xt::keep(xIndices), xt::all());
}

Am I making a copy of the array when xt::view() is returned as xt::xarray? I want to reduce copy of the data to minimum.

"Am I making a copy of the array when xt::view() is returned as xt::xarray?..." Yes


Am I making a copy of the array when xt::view() is returned as xt::xarray?

Yes because although xt::xview does not perform a copy of the underlying expression we still have the return type of the function sparsify as xt::xarray<float>(essentially returning by value) which means even conceptually, a copy is created using the return expression.

Thanks for the answer. What shall be the returned type to avoid copy of the data?

@MichalMajeran You can either have an out parameter or explicitly use return by ref. You're welcome.
